# Check status of all enabled items in a list of checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Wrapping my head around mvvm programming pattern.  Definitely a different way of thinking.

At this time, I have what is probably a simple question. While I could certainly "brute force" a solution, I'm sure there is something elegant out there which I am simply missing.

I have a list of checkboxes, some of which are enabled and some are disabled.  The how of that is irrelevant.  I also have a Select All toggle.

[image]

What I want to do, is to be able to evaluate the enabled features, to see if they have been selected (when determining whether or not to show the Select All as being checked) or to select all enabled features (ignoring the disabled ones) and then show a check beside Select All.

The "how" of that, insofar as an MVVM approach, is unclear to me.  What I have concocted so far:

xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label x:Name="labelFeatures" Content="Features" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_All" Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding AllFeatures}" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_1" Content="Feature 1" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Feature1Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Using_Feat_1}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_2" Content="Feature 2" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Feature2Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Using_Feat_2}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_3" Content="Feature 3" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Feature3Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Using_Feat_3}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_4" Content="Feature 4" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Feature4Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Using_Feat_4}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_5" Content="Feature 5" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Feature5Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Using_Feat_5}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
bool? _usingAllFeatures = null;
// If any feature is offered but unselected, the return status will be false (All Features will be unselected).
public bool AllFeatures
{
    get
    {
        _usingAllFeatures =
            (Feature1Enabled ? Using_Feat_1 : _usingAllFeatures)
          & (Feature2Enabled ? Using_Feat_2 : _usingAllFeatures)
          & (Feature3Enabled ? Using_Feat_3 : _usingAllFeatures)
          & (Feature4Enabled ? Using_Feat_4 : _usingAllFeatures)
          & (Feature5Enabled ? Using_Feat_5 : _usingAllFeatures);

        //_usingAllFeatures =
        //    (FeatureCSPEnabled    && Using_Feat_CSPKSP)
        //  & (FeatureJSPEnabled    && Using_Feat_JSP)
        //  & (FeatureJCPROVEnabled && Using_Feat_JCPROV)
        //  & (FeatureSDKEnabled    && Using_Feat_SDK)
        //  & (FeatureSNMPEnabled   && Using_Feat_SNMP);

        return _usingAllFeatures.HasValue && _usingAllFeatures.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        Using_Feat_1 = value;
        Using_Feat_2 = value;
        Using_Feat_3 = value;
        Using_Feat_4 = value;
        Using_Feat_5 = value;

        OnPropertiesChanged("AllFeatures");
    }
}
```

But, it's flaky and not right.  _usingAllFeatures remains true, even if all features are disabled.  Neither approach works - I'm always getting a false from features that are disabled, which winds up de-selecting the Select All, where in fact, it should actually be selected.

I am hoping to craft some form of solution that will, when checking the "all selected" status:

```
if checkbox is enabled
  and selected
    record "true" to _usingAllFeatures
  else if checkbox not selected
    record  "false" to _usingAllFeatures
else if checkbox not enabled
  do nothing
```

I'm probably overthinking this and not seeing the right solution.. what am I missing?

**UPDATE**:

OMG... Please help me fix this ugly brute:

```
public bool AllFeatures
{
    get
    {
        _usingAllFeatures = false;

        if (Feature1Enabled)
            if (Using_Feat_1)
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = false;
            }
        if (Feature2Enabled && _usingAllFeatures == true)
            if (Using_Feat_2)
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = false;
            }
        if (Feature3Enabled && _usingAllFeatures == true)
            if (Using_Feat_3)
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = false;
            }
        if (Feature4Enabled && _usingAllFeatures == true)
            if (Using_Feat_4)
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = false;
            }
        if (Feature5Enabled && _usingAllFeatures == true)
            if (Using_Feat_5)
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _usingAllFeatures = false;
            }

        return _usingAllFeatures;
    }
    set
    {
        //_usingAllFeatures = value;
        Using_Feat_1 = value;
        Using_Feat_2 = value;
        Using_Feat_3 = value;
        Using_Feat_4 = value;
        Using_Feat_5 = value;

        OnPropertiesChanged("AllFeatures");
    }
}
```

Yeah, it works.. but... ugh!  Please help me to a better solution!

I was reading about observable collections and multi levels of models.. but I don't understand it enough to see how to integrate that approach with a list of checkboxes that can be enabled / disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the root of your problem is the inconsistent state of `AllFeatures` being `false` when some features (not all) are selected, but resetting all features when setting the property to false.

So I suggest you de-couple the user interaction on `cb_FEAT_All` from the displayed state:

Implement a get-only `bool AllFeatures`:

```
public bool AllFeatures
{
    get
    {
        return
            (!Feature1Enabled || Using_Feat_1) &&
            (!Feature2Enabled || Using_Feat_2) /* ... more features */;
    }
}
```

Notify appropriate property changes in the features

```
private bool _Feature1Enabled;
public bool Feature1Enabled
{
    get { return _Feature1Enabled; }
    set
    {
        _Feature1Enabled = value;
        OnPropertiesChanged("Feature1Enabled");
        OnPropertiesChanged("AllFeatures");
    }
}

private bool _Using_Feat_1;
public bool Using_Feat_1
{
    get { return _Using_Feat_1; }
    set
    {
        _Using_Feat_1 = value;
        OnPropertiesChanged("Using_Feat_1");
        OnPropertiesChanged("AllFeatures");
    }
}
// more properties...
```

Create a method that handles changes:

```
void ExecToggleAllFeatures()
{
    var newVal = !AllFeatures;

    if (Feature1Enabled) Using_Feat_1 = newVal;
    if (Feature2Enabled) Using_Feat_2 = newVal;
    // ...
}
```

Create an `ICommand` that calls `ExecToggleAllFeatures` as `Execute` handler. Potentially use a `RelayCommand` (you can google it if you don't know it yet).

```
public ICommand ToggleCheckAllCommand { /* implement get/set */ }
```

Bind your checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_All" Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding AllFeatures,Mode=OneWay}" Command={Binding ToggleCheckAllCommand} Margin="6,0,0,0" />
```

You *could* also place the logic from `ExecToggleAllFeatures` into the `AllFeatures` setter, but I think it's not a good design choice (purely opinion based)

Answer (score 0):

Few steps:

Use MVVM framework. Choose one of the many, I personally use [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/)

First of all, put your features in a list of objects of class Feature:

```
    public class Feature : ReactiveObject // this contains INotifyPropertyChanged and so on
    {
     public string Name
            {
                get { return _name; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value); }
            }

     public bool Checked
            {
                get { return _checked; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _checked, value); }
            }

 public bool Enabled
            {
                get { return _enabled; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _enabled, value); }
            }
    }
```

In your view put:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label x:Name="labelFeatures" Content="Features" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_FEAT_All" Content="Select All" IsChecked="{Binding AllSelected}" Margin="6,0,0,0" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Features}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now, if you want to have more features, you just add another object to the list.

Now we will use some magick form ReactiveUI and maybe I will convince you to use Rx :)

In your ViewModel constructor we have to create our list:

```
    public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private bool _allSelected;

        public bool AllSelected
        {
            get { return _allSelected; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _allSelected, value); }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Features = new ReactiveList<Feature>
            {
                ChangeTrackingEnabled = true // this enabes few tricks
            };

            Features.ItemChanged.Where(x => x.PropertyName == nameof(Feature.Checked)).Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                // any time item in the list is checked, select/deselect all
                if (Features.All(x => x.Checked)) // feel free to filter out disabled features
                    AllSelected = true;
                else
                    AllSelected = false;
                // you can make AllSeleted nullable and make checkbox show "NotSpecified" state like in some installers, when not all, but some are selected
            });

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.AllSelected).Subscribe(x =>
            {
                // each time someone checks AllFeatures checkbox, check/uncheck all
                // x has the value of AllSelected
                using (Features.SuppressChangeNotifications()) // to prevent setting AllSelected to false after checking every item
                    foreach (var feature in Features)
                    {
                        feature.Checked = x;
                    }
            });

Features.Add(new Feature{Name="Feature 1", Enabled =  true, Checked = true}); // add all other features, maybe get them from database or from REST service, you name it

        }

        public ReactiveList<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    }
```